# validating a dictionary with lists that it all contains the same length

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which looks like this

```
dic = {'x': [1, 2], 'z': [1, 3], 'r': [4, 5]}
```

Am trying to figure out a way to check that all the values in the dictionary have the same list length.

I tried the following

```
if (len(dic['x']) == len(dic['r']) == len(dic['z'])):
```

this works, but am looking for a way todo it without knowing the keys of the dictionary as they may vary.. any one can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
vals = dic.values()
l = len(vals[0])
if all(len(item) == l for item in vals):
    # ok
```

Or, perhaps this:

```
lens = map(len, dic.values())
if len(set(lens)) == 1:
    # ok
```

Comment: note: fails on python 3.  dict views do not support indexing.

Comment: No need for a `lambda`:  `lens = map(len, dic.values())`

Answer (score 0):

This will work on both Python2 and 3:

```
>>> dic = {'x': [1, 2], 'z': [1, 3], 'r': [4, 5]}
>>> f = len(dic[next(iter(dic))])
>>> all(len(x) == f for x in dic.values())
True
```

If number of items are huge then it's better to iterate over just dict itself, as `dic.values()` will return a list of all values in Python2(You can use `dict.itervalues` to get an iterator in Python2).:

```
>>> all(len(dic[k]) == f for k in dic)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below handles the case where not all dictionary elements are lists.

```
def _all_lists_in_dict_have_the_same_length(data: dict) -> bool:
    items_length_set = set()
    for val in data.values():
        if not isinstance(val, list):
            continue
        items_length_set.add(len(val))
    if len(items_length_set) != 1:
        return False
    return True
```